# Filter Array within object using autocomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to filter on a array within a object based on a string using two filter methods. Here is what my object looks like.

```
[
  {
    "cat": "Accommodation and Food Service Activities",
    "value": [
      {
        "sic": "55",
        "desc": "Accommodation"
      },
      {
       "sic": "56",
        "desc": "Food and beverage service activities"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "cat": "Activities Of Extraterritorial Organisations and Bodies",
    "value": [
      {
       "sic": "99",
        "desc": "Activities of extraterritorial organisations and bodies"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am trying to filter on the `value.desc` and return the `cat`

Here is what I have so far

```
filteredIndustries(industry: string) {
    if (industry) {
      return this.industries.filter(sector => {
        if (sector.value) {
          sector.value.findIndex( v => {
            return v.desc.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(industry.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0;
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return this.industries;
    }
```

and here is my html,

```
 <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput placeholder="Industry" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="industryCtrl">
    </md-input-container>

    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayIndustry.bind(this)">
      <md-option *ngFor="let industry of filteredIndustry | async" [value]="industry">
        {{ industry.cat }}
      </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
```

So when I enter food, it should filter on `value.desc` and return `cat` which should be `Accommodation and Food Service Activities`

But I am not getting any return value even though my return result is true.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a good first question, you posted your code and explained your problem properly, making easy to help you. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filter` callback function misses a return statement, if `findIndex` returns something bigger than -1 you should return `true`;

```
filteredIndustries(industry: string) {
    if (industry) {
      return this.industries.filter(sector => {
        if (sector.value) {
          return -1 < sector.value.findIndex( v => { //HERE
            return v.desc.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(industry.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0;
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return this.industries;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just that the function that you passed to filter() always return undefined and it is a "falsy" value, so it filters out all elements of the array this.industries

Comment: Thanks for your help, this helped me to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `some()` instead of `findIndex()`. `indexOf` returns -1 if the specified string was not found.

```js
var industries = [
  {
    "cat": "Accommodation and Food Service Activities",
    "value": [
      {
        "sic": "55",
        "desc": "Accommodation"
      },
      {
       "sic": "56",
        "desc": "Food and beverage service activities"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "cat": "Activities Of Extraterritorial Organisations and Bodies",
    "value": [
      {
       "sic": "99",
        "desc": "Activities of extraterritorial organisations and bodies"
      }
    ]
  }
] 

var industry = 'food'
var b = industries.filter(sector => {
  if (sector.value) {
    return sector.value.some( v => v.desc.toLowerCase().indexOf(industry) >= 0 );
  } else {
    return industries
  }
});

console.log(b)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not return a value. Thanks any way. sorted it out

Comment: I've edited my answer to demonstrate that my code works.